# How to implement row level access control in PostgreSQL using Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am building a multi-tenant backend using Node, Express, PostgreSQL and Sequelize. All of my tenant's data is stored in the same table. Right now, I am using the WHERE clause to filter data and restrict one tenant's data from others but I would like to add another layer of security using the row-level access control feature of PostgreSQL. I found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/multi-tenant-data-isolation-with-postgresql-row-level-security/) article very helpful but it does not cover the implementation in NodeJS.